# Create Message voice action for non en-us locales

Tags: android, app-actions

I would like to know which are my posibilities as a developer to implements a send message voice action, in a messaging app (like a custom Telegram app), for spanish users. I want to implement the send new message action, I does not interested in replying to received messages (this is already implemented).

This is an example of I want to implements:
[Create Message action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljFH5.jpg)

1. The user tells an utterance like "I would like to send a message with whatsapp".
2. A widget asks for a contact to send the message (if the user did not especificated one).
3. The app sends the message.

This is the same working example for spanish language: [Create Message action (spanish)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oDjC.jpg)

I already know that there are built-in intents but the CREATE_MESSAGE built-in intent is only available for en-us locale. I also checked the custom intents but there are also only availables for en-us locale as I know. Which more options do I have?

PD:  My final goal is to make the app compatible for Android Auto so I'm making it compatible with google assistant first.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you note, the [`actions.intent.CREATE_MESSAGE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/app-actions/built-in-intents/communications/create-message) BII is only available in en-US right now. This is probably the best one, since it provides getting and sending a message without any additional work.

You may want to see if [`actions.intent.OPEN_APP_FEATURE`](https://developer.android.com/reference/app-actions/built-in-intents/common/open-app-feature) will work for your needs. It has the downside that it does not have the fields available in `CREATE_MESSAGE`, but it might be a useful way to open the app.

However...

If you're planning on [targeting Android Auto](https://developer.android.com/training/cars/messaging), that platform is even more restricted. If you're building an Android Auto app, you are [limited](https://youtu.be/hhdVMLG5Y10?t=612) to use only the `actions.intent.GET_PARKING_FACILITY` or `actions.intent.GET_CHARGING_STATIONS` BIIs. If you are willing to have it return a widget, you get a little more flexibility in [what BIIs it accepts](https://youtu.be/hhdVMLG5Y10?t=949), but these don't let you send a message or open the app (even in en-US).

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. So, how are this actions implemented on apps like WhatsApp or the official Telegram app? I am opened to use another framework, the app actions are the only way to implement this action?

Comment: I don't know what behavior in WhatsApp or Telegram you're talking about, exactly. You may want to update the original question to illustrate exactly what the user does in these apps that you're trying to emulate.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have already updated the post with images. In these apps (in whatsapp for example) the user can invoke an action for sending a text message with spanish utterances.